# PhpSpreadsheet xlsx to PDF with mPDF -> I can't delete grid lines and show table borders

Tags: php, phpexcel, mpdf, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to generate a PDF invoice by XLSX template with phpspreadsheet.

> Use php7.3 version, "mpdf/mpdf": "^8.0" and
>   "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.10"

```
$path = 'ejemplo2.xlsx';
$inputFileType = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($path);
$objReader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($path);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A:G')->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('#ffffff');

$pdfPath = 'ejemplo2.pdf';
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Mpdf');
$writer->save($pdfPath);
```

The original xlsx and generated pdf look like: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX4kp.png)

I tried to use $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setShowGridLines(false); but so I can't show the table borders.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

it probably has something to do with your version of php, seems like it is outdated, try to update it to the latest version. I had similar problem and updating my XAMPP fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am triying with Dompdf and run OK.

```
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Dompdf');
```